# Mikrotik switched VLAN configuration

Tags: switch, vlan, mikrotik, routeros

With Routerboard 450G I want to configure the 5 Ethernet ports as follows:

- ether1: vlan3, untagged
- ether2: vlan1, untagged
- ether3: vlan2, untagged
- ether4: vlan2, untagged
- ether5: vlan1-vlan3, tagged

Within vlan1, the device should have IP 10.7.1.3/24.

However, when I want to ping the Routerboard it is not reachable. I configured the device the following way:

1. Include ether1 in switching:

```
/interface ethernet switch print
Flags: I - invalid
 #   NAME                                    TYPE          MIRROR-SOURCE                                  MIRROR-TARGET                                  SWITCH-ALL-PORTS
 0   switch1                                 Atheros-8316  none                                           none                                           yes
```

2. Switch all ports together:

```
/interface ethernet print
Flags: X - disabled, R - running, S - slave
 #    NAME                                      MTU MAC-ADDRESS       ARP        MASTER-PORT                                    SWITCH
 0 R  ether1                                   1500 E4:8D:8C:18:D5:A1 enabled    none                                           switch1
 1  S ether2                                   1500 E4:8D:8C:18:D5:A2 enabled    ether1                                         switch1
 2  S ether3                                   1500 E4:8D:8C:18:D5:A3 enabled    ether1                                         switch1
 3  S ether4                                   1500 E4:8D:8C:18:D5:A4 enabled    ether1                                         switch1
 4 RS ether5                                   1500 E4:8D:8C:18:D5:A5 enabled    ether1                                         switch1
```

3. Configure ports 1-4 to remove VLAN tags and port 5 to add them; set default VLAN IDs:

```
/interface ethernet switch port print
Flags: I - invalid
 #   NAME                                                         SWITCH                                                         VLAN-MODE VLAN-HEADER    DEFAULT-VLAN-ID
 0   ether1                                                       switch1                                                        secure    always-strip                 3
 1   ether2                                                       switch1                                                        secure    always-strip                 1
 2   ether3                                                       switch1                                                        secure    always-strip                 2
 3   ether4                                                       switch1                                                        secure    always-strip                 2
 4   ether5                                                       switch1                                                        secure    add-if-missing               0
 5   switch1-cpu                                                  switch1                                                        fallback  leave-as-is                  0
```

4. Wire the VLANs together. As can be seen, ether2 and ether5 are connected through vlan1:

```
/interface ethernet switch vlan print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid
 #   SWITCH                                                                         VLAN-ID PORTS
 0   switch1                                                                              3 ether1
                                                                                            ether5
 1   switch1                                                                              1 ether2
                                                                                            ether5
 2   switch1                                                                              2 ether3
                                                                                            ether4
                                                                                            ether5
```

5. Finally, add IP address to ether2:

```
/ip addr print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
 #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE
 0   10.7.1.3/24        10.7.1.0        ether2
```

Port 5 is directly connected to a managed switch which outputs vlan1-vlan3 tagged. The Routerboard cannot be pinged.

Do I miss something in the configuration or do I understand the concept wrong? (To my understanding, it would be sufficient to add the IP to ether2, because it is switched to vlan1 on ether5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the routerboard can only communicate to/from the master interface in a switch.

Secondly, you need to tag this with a vlan interface.

Finally (depending on the routerboard) you need to add switch1-cpu to the vlan port list for VLAN 1 in switch1.

So:

`/int vlan add vlan-id=1 name=vlan1 interface=ether1`

`/ip addr add 10.7.1.3/24 interface=vlan1`

and (depending on the routerboard - be sure to remove the old entry first):

`/interface ethernet switch vlan add switch=switch1 ports=ether2,ether5,switch1-cpu vlan-id=1`

Comment: Great! I think what is missing here is `/interface ethernet switch vlan add switch=switch1 ports=ether2,ether5,switch1-cpu vlan-id=1`. Otherwise packets are not passed to CPU(?). Also, could you add how switch1-cpu switch port should be configured (in terms of vlan-mode, vlan-header, ...)? Currently it's set to vlan-mode=fallback and vlan-header=leave-as-is (as can be seen above)

Comment: switch1-cpu port should be fine as it is. Those settings are usually used for untagging vlans on ports and vlan port security.